# What eclipse version to use for: Java, Python, and Android

Tags: eclipse

I want to install eclipse to develop in Java, Python, Android platform. What is the best suitable? And what are the pros\cons?

- on a Windows 7
- on a mac OSX 10.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I wont recommend the use of Eclipse to develop in all of these languages.

I use the following:

**Java** -> [Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/junosr1)

**Python** -> [PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) / [PyScripter](http://code.google.com/p/pyscripter/)

**Android** -> [ADT Bundle](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) (New Eclipse based IDE for Android by Google)

---

If you insists using eclipse for all of those languages then use [Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/junosr1) with [PyDev](http://pydev.org/) plugin for Python and [Android SDK Tools](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html) for Android.

Comment: Actually I intended to use eclipse for all three. With plug ins. Is that advisable?

Comment: It's really not advisable.. only if you really like eclipse.
I added the recommended eclipse version with plugins.